# Flutter,how to give row space for gridview

Tags: flutter

```
 Widget selectTime(double itemHeight, double itemWidth) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: GridView.builder(
        primary: false,
        // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: (itemHeight / itemWidth),
        ),
        itemCount: timeslotsList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0XFF9CA3F4),
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                    topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                    bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                    bottomRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
          );
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
```

I am implementing gridview in my flutter app.I created the grid successfully now i want give spacing after even rows (Ex:2,4,6) after the 2nd row i want to give row spacing for the gridview

Comment: Could you provide a [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to have the row spacing inside the GridView, you may use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view). This plugin has support for dynamic column and row sizes.

Here's a sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
        child: StaggeredGridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          staggeredTiles: _staggeredTiles,
          mainAxisSpacing: 4,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
          children: _tiles,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const List<StaggeredTile> _staggeredTiles = <StaggeredTile>[
  StaggeredTile.count(2, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(2, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(4, 1), // Spacer
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 2),
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 2),
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(3, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(4, 1),
];

const List<Widget> _tiles = <Widget>[
  SampleTile(Colors.green, Icons.widgets),
  SampleTile(Colors.lightBlue, Icons.wifi),
  SampleTile(null, null), // Spacer
  SampleTile(Colors.amber, Icons.panorama_wide_angle),
  SampleTile(Colors.brown, Icons.map),
  SampleTile(Colors.deepOrange, Icons.send),
  SampleTile(Colors.indigo, Icons.airline_seat_flat),
  SampleTile(Colors.red, Icons.bluetooth),
  SampleTile(Colors.pink, Icons.battery_alert),
  SampleTile(Colors.purple, Icons.desktop_windows),
  SampleTile(Colors.blue, Icons.radio),
];

class SampleTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const SampleTile(this.backgroundColor, this.iconData, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final IconData? iconData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Return an empty Container if [backgroundColor] and [iconData] is null
    return (backgroundColor != null && iconData != null)
        ? Card(
            color: backgroundColor,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  child: Icon(
                    iconData,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Container();
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]